# Date format problem in new lotus domino document

Tags: c#, .net, lotus, lotus-domino

I have problem with data format. When I create document in lotus database (in lotus client) date is inserted without time

`Field Name: data_fim` 
`Data Type: Time/Date` 
`Data Length: 8 bytes` 
`Seq Num: 1` 
`Dup Item ID: 0` 
`Field Flags: SUMMARY`

'2011-01-26`

when I create/change it from C# it contains time:

`Field Name: data_inicio` 
`Data Type: Time/Date` 
`Data Length: 8 bytes` 
`Seq Num: 12` 
`Dup Item ID: 0` 
`Field Flags: SUMMARY`

`2010-12-15 00:00:00 CET`

Command used for change doc

`doc.ReplaceItemValue("data_inicio", Convert.ToDateTime( "2010-12-15"));`

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use [DateTime formatting](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your Lotus Notes Date Field. You need to have the property "Display Time" checked.

On the Form go to your date field and then click on properties
On the Second Tab you will see two sections: On Display -->Display Date & Display Time
Make sure both of those are checked.

Comment: I'am not able to change anything on lotus application. The problem is that on summary list I see 2 documents (one created in lotus, one in C#) as 2 separate dates (one with time shown, one without)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using ReplaceItemValue and Convert, if you use a notesDateTime object, you can create a date-time field with the date-only component. For example:

```
...
Dim dt As notesDateTime
Set dt = New NotesDateTime ("1/1/2011")
set doc.testDate = dt
call doc.save (true, false)
...
```